# 'KeyboardEvent.keyCode' modifier on 'v-on' directive is deprecated. Using 'KeyboardEvent.key' instead in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am migrating my application vue 2 to vue 3. While running the application, i am getting some deprecation error.

In my keyboard event modifier, i was using numbers and key for keyboard event. But, this concept is deprecated so i am getting errors. I am not sure how to use it now?

**Previously**

```
 @keyup.ctrl.86="onUpdateEvent()"
```

I am getting error because of using numbers. How to resolve those?

Answer (score 1):

You can find this in the docs: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/keycode-modifiers.html#_3-x-syntax

It looks like you should be using the kebab-case name of the key rather than a numeric keycode, so you would use `@keyup.ctrl.v` in this case.